# print with incremental order all combinations of string without repetition

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

to do so I am doing:

```
    string[] combinations = Combinations("LEQN");
    foreach (string s in combinations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

and method Combinations:

```
public static string[] Combinations(string str)
         {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))  throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input");
            if (str.Length == 1)            return new string[] { str };
            // read the last character
            char c = str[str.Length - 1];
            // apart from the last character send remaining string for further processing
            string[] returnArray = Combinations(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1));
            // List to keep final string combinations
            List<string> finalArray = new List<string>();
            // add whatever is coming from the previous routine
            foreach (string s in returnArray)
                finalArray.Add(s);
            // take the last character
            finalArray.Add(c.ToString());
            // take the combination between the last char and the returning strings from the previous routine
            foreach (string s in returnArray)
                finalArray.Add(s + c);

            return finalArray.ToArray();
        }
```

this would print:

```
L
E
LE
Q
LQ
EQ
LEQ
N
LN
EN
LEN
QN
LQN
EQN
LEQN
```

which is correct, however I woul like to get result like

```
L   N   Q   E   LN  NQ  EL  QE  LNQ ELN QEL NQE NQEL
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you explain what is special about that particular desired ordering? Is it the increasing length, or something else specific about the combination patterns involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort based on string [length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using LINQ [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (string s in combinations.OrderBy(str => str.Length))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Is there other neat way without using LINQ?

Comment: The `Combinations` recursive method is implemented in such a way that ordering is required at some point (with or without LINQ). You can change re implement this method using some iterative approach that gets first all combinations of length 1, then all combinations of length 2 and so on (basically a complete rewrite).